# WPF property not reflected immediately (only last change is reflected)

Tags: c#, wpf, properties

I want to change color of WPF button using C#.

Let's say I have a WPF button which color I would like to change for a 1 second:

```
<Button Name="Button1"></Button>
```

I also have a button which starts that change:

```
<Button Name="ProcessControl" Click="ProcessControl_Click">Start</Button>
```

I have C# code which does not make any visible change:

```
private void ProcessControl_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        Brush background = button.Background;
        Button1.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Yellow;
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Button1.Background = background;
}
```

But, if I would write this code, which changes color, doesn't wait a second and it does not restore old color, it works:

```
private void ProcessControl_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        Brush background = button.Background;
        Button1.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Yellow;
}
```

It's the same thing with all WPF elements and properties. If some property is changed twice, only last change will reflect.

I've also tried to call:

```
this.UpdateLayout();
```

but it's not fixing the problem.

I've tried using background worker, but it also does not fix my problem.

Does anyone now how to immediately reflect property change in WPF using C#?

Comment: It's likely your `Thread.Sleep(1000)` is blocking the UI thread so the button does not get repainted in the new color.  You should probably do this using animations instead http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're blocking the UI thread with Sleep, which means the updated property cannot be rendered.  If you're using a version that supports async/await, you could try this instead:

```
private async void ProcessControl_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        Brush background = button.Background;
        Button1.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Yellow;
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Button1.Background = background;
}
```

This registers a callback on the UI thread to fire after one second (assuming the Click event handler is called from the UI thread, which it should always be unless you call the method manually.)

Comment: Using `await` like this feels so *wrong*. It works of course; good answer!

Comment: @BradleyDotNET, I like to use `Task.Delay` as a short-hand version of registering a timer callback on the UI thread; I pretty much always use this in place of explicit timers now.  Granted, having an async void method isn't a great practice; when you generalize the above pattern to production code, you definitely have to watch out for 'what if' scenarios that can change your app state in the delay period (something that generally is suppressed when you sleep the UI thread.)  A timer callback has these same issues, though perhaps it's less obvious with an await.

Answer (score 0):

The first code sample won't work because you block the UI thread with `Thread.Sleep`. Basically, you (on the UI thread)

1. Change the color
2. Sleep (note the UI hasn't had a chance to update yet!)
3. Change the color back
4. UI updates, to the old color!

Doing this on a background worker *could* work if you changed the color, then slept the second change on another thread. Of course, that change would have to be marshaled back onto the UI thread, so if you weren't careful in where you put the `Sleep` you would see the same behavior.

Realistically, you should just change the color, then set a timer. In the `Elapsed` event of that timer, set the color back. You could also just use async/await so the UI thread doesn't block, as in Dan Bryant's answer.